# How to stop data measuring without stopping the whole script

Tags: python, linux, matplotlib, mouse

I am using some code from here to fetch x, y deltas from a usb mouse on my linux laptop. It's a script that gets the deltas and plots it with matplotlib. But the main problem is, that i cant stop the measurement without killing the whole script. i am still a beginner in terms of programming, so any help would be nice.

my code:

```
import struct
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
from drawnow import * 

file = open( "/dev/input/mouse2", "rb" );
test = []
plt.ion()

def makeFig():
 plt.plot(test)
 #plt.show()

def getMouseEvent():
  buf = file.read(3);
  button = ord( buf[0] );
  bLeft = button & 0x1;
  x,y = struct.unpack( "bb", buf[1:] )  
  print ("x: %d, y: %d\n" % (x, y) )  
  return x,y


while True:
 test.append(getMouseEvent())
 drawnow(makeFig)

file.close();
```

Comment: Do you just want to toggle the appending of mouse data to `test`, or do you want to break out of the `while` loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decide under what condition you want the script to stop. For example this will stop after 5 seconds:

```
start_time = time.time()
elapsed = 0
while elapsed < 5:
    elapsed = time.time() - start_time:
    test.append(getMouseEvent())

drawnow(makeFig)
```

If you want it to stop after 100 measurements:

```
count = 0
while count < 100:
    count += 1
    test.append(getMouseEvent())
    time.sleep(1)  # <--  optional

drawnow(makeFig)
```

Comment: I like the first of your solutions. I actually tried the counting thing before asking here, i forgot to tell^^